# Does process Builder Scheduled Action recalculates the scheduled time for formula field?

Tags: process-builder, formula-field, scheduled-action

I have custom solution to replace standard Contract expiration Notice (because of need to change email template and different values for days).

So I created custom picklist field "Owner Expiration Notice" and custom formula field "Date Of Notification" = Contract.EndDate - VALUE ( TEXT( Owner_Expiration_Notice__c ) ).

In Process builder, I want to schedule an email template based on Date Of Notification. User have ability to change this field in future and I am not sure how does PB work in this case.

Based on official documentation it should automatically recalculate that time, but as it is formula, I am not sure.

> - If the referenced field value changes and the schedule hasn’t been processed, Salesforce recalculates the scheduled time for the actions using the updated field value.
>     For example, a process emails an opportunity owner seven days before the opportunity close date. The close date is set to 2/20/20XX, and Salesforce schedules the email to be sent on 2/13/20XX. Before the email is sent, the close date is updated to 2/10/20XX. Salesforce recalculates the scheduled time and schedules the email to be sent on 2/3/20XX.

This is how my PB node looks like:
[image: PB node]
[image: Time based action based on formula field]

So my main question is if User change Owner_Expiration_Notice__c, so Date Of Notification will also change, will Salesforce recalculates the scheduled time?

Comment: I think a good way to test would be to just have a formula field pull in a separate date field you can edit in a test environment. Have it set to a future date and enter the PB and be scheduled. After it's been scheduled, edit the date field so that it's back-dated (which means it should send immediately or within the next 5-15 minutes).

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Thanks for the advice, I tried it, but it doesn't work. I am dealing with this issue and there is lots of other issues connected to my need :/ 
In past I made it with other checkbox fields and in process builder I was cancelling notification and in other step creating new. So I probably don't have other option, what I consider as a workaround and not most optimal solution :(